# Fix touchDragged logic

Tags: libgdx

**What i want:**

I want allow the user to drag and drop the actors he puts on the screen

1) An actor (32x32 pixel) can be put in a certain area defined by me (a centered rectangle 5x5, 32 pixel each cell)

2) The actors are snapped to an imaginary grid of the screen when added to the stage.

3) This snap to grid is needed also during the drag and drop

4) An actor can't be moved on another one

5) An actor must be rotated by 90 degrees when the user clicks on it

6) The actor can't be moved outside the bounds

**What actually i get:**

1) ok
2) ok
3) ok (with bugs)
4) not implemented yet
5) ok (with bugs)
6) not implemented yet

**The bugs are:**

1) The rotations is applied in any case. I don't want this behavior. I don't want to rotate an actor if the user is just doing drag and drop. (i know that this happens because i put this part of the code in the touchDown method)

2) This is hard to describe with my english, i'll try. 
I put an actor and i can move it (when i say "move" i mean drag and drop).
I put a second actor and i can move it.
Now, if i try to move the first actor i put, the second one moves over the first (overlapping to it) and starts moving along with it!

Now the code:

**Events in the GameStage**

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    translateScreenToWorldCoordinates(screenX, screenY);

    // check if the user clicked or not in the center area
    if(!centerArea.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
        return true;
    }

    // rotation
    Iterator<Square> squareIterator = squares.iterator();
    while(squareIterator.hasNext()) {
        Square nextSquare = squareIterator.next();
        if(nextSquare.getBounds().contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
            nextSquare.rotate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    // add an Actor

    touchPoint.set(touchPoint.x - Constants.SQUARE_SIZE / 2, touchPoint.y - Constants.SQUARE_SIZE / 2, 0f);

    float snapX = Math.round((touchPoint.x / Constants.SQUARE_SIZE)) * Constants.SQUARE_SIZE;
    float snapY = Math.round((touchPoint.y / Constants.SQUARE_SIZE)) * Constants.SQUARE_SIZE;

    Square square = new Square(snapX, snapY);
    squares.add(square);
    addActor(square);

    return true;
}

public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {

    Vector3 newTouchPoint = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0f);
    getCamera().unproject(newTouchPoint.set(screenX, screenY, 0f));

    Square next = null;

    Iterator<Square> squareIterator = squares.listIterator();
    while(squareIterator.hasNext()) {
        next = squareIterator.next();

        if(next.getBounds().contains(newTouchPoint.x, newTouchPoint.y)) {

            next.setX(newTouchPoint.x - Constants.SQUARE_SIZE / 2);
            next.setY(newTouchPoint.y - Constants.SQUARE_SIZE / 2);

            continue;
        }
    }

    newTouchPoint.set(newTouchPoint.x - Constants.SQUARE_SIZE / 2, newTouchPoint.y - Constants.SQUARE_SIZE / 2, 0f);
    float snapX = Math.round((newTouchPoint.x / Constants.SQUARE_SIZE)) * Constants.SQUARE_SIZE;
    float snapY = Math.round((newTouchPoint.y / Constants.SQUARE_SIZE)) * Constants.SQUARE_SIZE;
    next.setX(snapX);
    next.setY(snapY);

    return true;
}

private void translateScreenToWorldCoordinates(int x, int y) {
    getCamera().unproject(touchPoint.set(x, y, 0f));
}
```

**Actor**

```
public class Square extends GameActor {

    private float rotation;
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

    public Square(float x, float y) {
        super(x, y);
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void initializeSprite() {
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(Constants.SQUARE_LOCATION));
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateBounds() {
        bounds.setPosition(x, y);
    }

    public void rotate() {
        rotation -= 90;
        if(rotation <= -360) {
            rotation = 0;
        }
        setRotation(rotation);
    }

    public void setX(float x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(float y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

        /*shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        shapeRenderer.rect(bounds.getX(), bounds.getY(), Constants.SQUARE_SIZE, Constants.SQUARE_SIZE);
        shapeRenderer.end();*/
        //batch.begin();

        batch.draw(texture, x, y, texture.getWidth() / 2, texture.getHeight() / 2,
            texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight(), 1, 1, rotation, 0, 0, Constants.SQUARE_SIZE, Constants.SQUARE_SIZE, false, false);
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me, i'm new to Libgdx, thank you.

**UPDATE**

I fixed the rotation bug moving its logic inside the touchUp method.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, why not use `libgdx`'s [Drag and Drop feature](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/DragAndDrop.html)? A great video tutorial on this can be found [here](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDEQtwIwAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DiHQ2UsoWhCE&ei=U1GiVcW-LsyS7AbSiafIAg&usg=AFQjCNH2fMGYiwPKaE2wruKJ84BlkJzNHA&sig2=zZL6Cu2r_DLr0YJHLL2HFg).

Comment: I've already seen that video. Actually i'm not using skin, tables and so on.. so i don't know how to implement it in my code. I would like to fix my code, and then try to improve it. Moreover, my implementation seems easier.

Comment: The Drag and Drop feature is not specific for usage of Skins or Tables. In my opinion it's worth learning how to use this feature for your specific case since it's been tested and in use by many other users. In the long run, it'll save you time and effort.

Comment: For example, in the video he has already some items in an inventory that he can use to set the source and all the stuff. In my code, at the beginning, i have no actors. An actor is added when the user clicks with the mouse. THEN, that actor can be moved.

Comment: You can create the `Source` of the target when your `Actor` is created. Then add the `Source` to the `DragAndDrop` object with the `addSource` method.

Comment: Yes i tried and the actor does not move. The metod dragStart doesn't even get called. Moreover what should be my target?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83067/discussion-between-user3075478-and-user2016436).